# [Gazebo Garden] Black logos/icons/images

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all,

I just installed [gazebo garden](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu) with the binaries in ubuntu 22.04, the installation went well, no errors. But I am getting this weird error where the logos/icons/images are black (screenshot below). I also tried building from source and I get the same error. I tried resintalling qt, qml, gz, my gpu driver but it didn't work. Any ideas?

[image: image description]

Gz log:

```
[Msg] Gazebo Sim GUI    v7.0.0
[Dbg] [gz.cc:162] Subscribing to [/gazebo/starting_world].
[Msg] Gazebo Sim Quick start dialog
[Dbg] [gz.cc:164] Waiting for a world to be set from the GUI...
[Dbg] [Application.cc:96] Initializing application.
[Dbg] [Application.cc:122] Qt using OpenGL graphics interface
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:140] Reading Quick start menu config.
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:839] [QT] QSGTextureAtlas: texture atlas allocation failed, code=501
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:180] Shutting quick setup dialog
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:167] Terminating application.
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:260] Waiting for subscribers to [/gazebo/starting_world]...
[Msg] Received world [empty.sdf] from the GUI.
[Dbg] [gz.cc:168] Unsubscribing from [/gazebo/starting_world].
[Msg] Gazebo Sim Server v7.0.0
[Msg] Loading SDF world file[/usr/share/gz/gz-sim7/worlds/empty.sdf].
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:96] Initializing application.
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:122] Qt using OpenGL graphics interface
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:596] Create main window
[Msg] Serving entity system service on [/entity/system/add]
[Dbg] [Physics.cc:869] Loaded [gz::physics::dartsim::Plugin] from library [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-physics-6/engine-plugins/libgz-physics-dartsim-plugin.so]
[Dbg] [SystemManager.cc:62] Loaded system [gz::sim::systems::Physics] for entity [1]
[Msg] Create service on [/world/empty/create]
[Msg] Remove service on [/world/empty/remove]
[Msg] Pose service on [/world/empty/set_pose]
[Msg] Pose service on [/world/empty/set_pose_vector]
[Msg] Light configuration service on [/world/empty/light_config]
[Msg] Physics service on [/world/empty/set_physics]
[Msg] SphericalCoordinates service on [/world/empty/set_spherical_coordinates]
[Msg] Enable collision service on [/world/empty/enable_collision]
[Msg] Disable collision service on [/world/empty/disable_collision]
[Msg] Material service on [/world/empty/visual_config]
[Msg] Material service on [/world/empty/wheel_slip]
[Dbg] [SystemManager.cc:62] Loaded system [gz::sim::systems::UserCommands] for entity [1]
[Dbg] [SystemManager.cc:62] Loaded system [gz::sim::systems::SceneBroadcaster] for entity [1]
[Dbg] [SystemManager.cc:62] Loaded system [gz::sim::systems::Contact] for entity [1]
[Msg] Loaded level [3]
[Msg] Serving world controls on [/world/empty/control], [/world/empty/control/state] and [/world/empty/playback/control]
[Msg] Serving GUI information on [/world/empty/gui/info]
[Msg] World [empty] initialized with [1ms] physics profile.
[Msg] Serving world SDF generation service on [/world/empty/generate_world_sdf]
[Msg] Serving world names on [/gazebo/worlds]
[Msg] Resource path add service on [/gazebo/resource_paths/add].
[Msg] Resource path get service on [/gazebo/resource_paths/get].
[Msg] Resource path resolve service on [/gazebo/resource_paths/resolve].
[Msg] Resource paths published on [/gazebo/resource_paths].
[Msg] Server control service on [/server_control].
[Msg] Found no publishers on /stats, adding root stats topic
[Msg] Found no publishers on /clock, adding root clock topic
[Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:507] Creating PostUpdate worker threads: 3
[Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:518] Creating postupdate worker thread (0)
[Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:518] Creating postupdate worker thread (1)
[Msg] Serving scene information on [/world/empty/scene/info]
[Msg] Serving graph information on [/world/empty/scene/graph]
[Msg] Serving full state on [/world/empty/state]
[Msg] Serving full state (async) on [/world/empty/state_async]
[Msg] Publishing scene information on [/world/empty/scene/info]
[Msg] Publishing entity deletions on [/world/empty/scene/deletion]
[Msg] Publishing state changes on [/world/empty/state]
[Msg] Publishing pose messages on [/world/empty/pose/info]
[Msg] Publishing dynamic pose messages on [/world/empty/dynamic_pose/info]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:112:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:105:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:98:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:102:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:27:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Dbg] [PathManager.cc:67] Requesting resource paths through [/gazebo/resource_paths/get]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/Gazebo/GazeboDrawer.qml:241:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/Gazebo/GazeboDrawer.qml:147:3: QML Dialog: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/Gazebo/GazeboDrawer.qml:147:3: QML Dialog: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:340] GUI requesting list of world names. The server may be busy downloading resources. Please be patient.
[GUI] [Dbg] [PathManager.cc:56] Received resource paths.
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:398] Requesting GUI from [/world/empty/gui/info]...
[GUI] [Dbg] [GuiRunner.cc:149] Requesting initial state from [/world/empty/state]...
[GUI] [Msg] Loading config [/home/gus/.gz/sim/7/gui.config]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [MinimalScene]
[GUI] [Dbg] [MinimalScene.cc:622] Creating gz-rendering interface for OpenGL
[GUI] [Dbg] [MinimalScene.cc:622] Creating gz-rendering interface for OpenGL
[GUI] [Dbg] [MinimalScene.cc:776] Creating render thread interface for OpenGL
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[Dbg] [EntityComponentManager.cc:1613] Updated state thread iterators: 8 threads processing around 1 entities each.
[Wrn] [Component.hh:144] Trying to serialize component with data type [N3sdf3v135WorldE], which doesn't have `operator<<`. Component will not be serialized.
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [3D View] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [MinimalScene] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-7/plugins/libMinimalScene.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [EntityContextMenuPlugin]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:57:5: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Entity Context Menu] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [EntityContextMenuPlugin] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-7/plugins/gui/libEntityContextMenuPlugin.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [GzSceneManager]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Scene Manager] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [GzSceneManager] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-7/plugins/gui/libGzSceneManager.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [InteractiveViewControl]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Camera view controller topic advertised on [/gui/camera/view_control]
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Interactive view control] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [InteractiveViewControl] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-7/plugins/libInteractiveViewControl.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [CameraTracking]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Camera tracking] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [CameraTracking] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-7/plugins/libCameraTracking.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [MarkerManager]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Listening to stats on [/world/empty/stats]
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Marker Manager] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [MarkerManager] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-7/plugins/libMarkerManager.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [SelectEntities]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Select entities] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [SelectEntities] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-7/plugins/gui/libSelectEntities.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [Spawn]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/Spawn/Spawn.qml:32:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Spawn] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [Spawn] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-7/plugins/gui/libSpawn.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [VisualizationCapabilities]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] View as transparent service on [/gui/view/transparent]
[GUI] [Msg] View as wireframes service on [/gui/view/wireframes]
[GUI] [Msg] View center of mass service on [/gui/view/com]
[GUI] [Msg] View inertia service on [/gui/view/inertia]
[GUI] [Msg] View collisions service on [/gui/view/collisions]
[GUI] [Msg] View joints service on [/gui/view/joints]
[GUI] [Msg] View frames service on [/gui/view/frames]
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Visualization capabilities] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [VisualizationCapabilities] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-7/plugins/gui/libVisualizationCapabilities.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [WorldControl]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/WorldControl/WorldControl.qml:30:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Using world control service [/world/empty/control]
[GUI] [Msg] Listening to stats on [/world/empty/stats]
[GUI] [Dbg] [WorldControl.cc:250] Using an event to share WorldControl msgs with the server
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [World control] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [WorldControl] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-7/plugins/libWorldControl.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [WorldStats]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Listening to stats on [/world/empty/stats]
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [World stats] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [WorldStats] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-7/plugins/libWorldStats.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [Shapes]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Shapes] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [Shapes] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-7/plugins/gui/libShapes.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [Lights]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Lights] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [Lights] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-7/plugins/gui/libLights.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [TransformControl]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/TransformControl/TransformControl.qml:104:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/TransformControl/TransformControl.qml:99:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/TransformControl/TransformControl.qml:94:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/TransformControl/TransformControl.qml:89:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Transform control] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [TransformControl] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-7/plugins/gui/libTransformControl.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [Screenshot]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Screenshot service on [/gui/screenshot]
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Screenshot] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [Screenshot] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-7/plugins/libScreenshot.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [CopyPaste]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Copy/Paste] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [CopyPaste] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-7/plugins/gui/libCopyPaste.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [ComponentInspector]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Component inspector] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [ComponentInspector] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-7/plugins/gui/libComponentInspector.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:453] Loading plugin [EntityTree]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityTree/EntityTree.qml:148:7: QML ToolButton: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Plugin.cc:182] The `ignition-gui` element is deprecated. Please use `gz-gui` instead.
[GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Entity tree] to main window
[GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [EntityTree] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-7/plugins/gui/libEntityTree.so]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:323] Loading window config
[GUI] [Msg] Using server control service [/server_control]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:610] Applying config
[GUI] [Wrn] [Component.hh:189] Trying to deserialize component with data type [N3sdf3v135WorldE], which doesn't have `operator>>`. Component will not be deserialized.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityTree/EntityTree.qml:148:7: QML ToolButton: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/WorldStats/WorldStats.qml:53:3: QML RowLayout: Binding loop detected for property "x"
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Dbg] [MinimalScene.cc:622] Creating gz-rendering interface for OpenGL
[GUI] [Dbg] [MinimalScene.cc:776] Creating render thread interface for OpenGL
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:839] [QT] QSGTextureAtlas: texture atlas allocation failed, code=501
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/Gazebo/GazeboDrawer.qml:147:3: QML Dialog: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
[GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [gz-rendering-ogre2]
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to create dri screen
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to create dri screen
[GUI] [Dbg] [MinimalScene.cc:571] Create scene [scene]
[GUI] [Dbg] [MinimalScene.cc:808] Creating texture node render interface for OpenGL
[GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [gz-rendering-ogre2]
[GUI] [Dbg] [TransformControl.cc:447] TransformControl plugin is using camera [scene::Camera(65527)]
[GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [gz-rendering-ogre2]
[GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [gz-rendering-ogre2]
[GUI] [Dbg] [Spawn.cc:289] Spawn plugin is using camera [scene::Camera(65527)]
[GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [gz-rendering-ogre2]
[GUI] [Dbg] [SelectEntities.cc:452] SelectEntities plugin is using camera [scene::Camera(65527)]
[GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [gz-rendering-ogre2]
[GUI] [Dbg] [MarkerManager.cc:171] Advertise /marker/list service.
[GUI] [Dbg] [MarkerManager.cc:181] Advertise /marker/list.
[GUI] [Dbg] [MarkerManager.cc:191] Advertise /marker_array.
[GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [gz-rendering-ogre2]
[GUI] [Dbg] [CameraTracking.cc:171] CameraTrackingPrivate plugin is moving camera [scene::Camera(65527)]
[GUI] [Msg] Move to service on [/gui/move_to]
[GUI] [Msg] Follow service on [/gui/follow]
[GUI] [Msg] Move to pose service on [/gui/move_to/pose]
[GUI] [Msg] Camera pose topic advertised on [/gui/camera/pose]
[GUI] [Msg] Follow offset service on [/gui/follow/offset]
[GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [gz-rendering-ogre2]
[GUI] [Dbg] [InteractiveViewControl.cc:133] InteractiveViewControl plugin is moving camera [scene::Camera(65527)]
[GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [gz-rendering-ogre2]
[GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [gz-rendering-ogre2]
[GUI] [Dbg] [EntityContextMenuPlugin.cc:79] Entity context menu plugin is using camera [scene::Camera(65527)]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:845] [QT] file::/Gazebo/GazeboDrawer.qml:147:3: QML Dialog: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
```

**EDIT:**

glxinfo:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/1d54ffc795811c878a8f762093d2d4db

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28488/%5Bgazebo-garden%5D-black-logos/icons/images/) by [rezenders](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26928/rezenders/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I fixed it by removing `libqt5quick5-gles`

```
apt remove libqt5quick5-gles
```

I found the answers in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288506/black-icons-after-reinstalling-kubuntu-desktop)

---

Originally posted by [rezenders](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26928/rezenders/) with karma: 5 on 2022-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0